# General steps to create a custom module in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a custom module that is fairly similar to the modal provided in the ui.bootstrap library. I would like to be able to open and close it via a service, and pass some options. The problem, is, I'm somewhat new to angular, and I'm not entirely sure how this should be done.

I've read up on how to create a custom modules (this was a great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109291/write-custom-module-for-angularjs)), And I understand that I'm going need a service in order to open it programatically, But after looking at the source code for I'm somewhat lost. I'm assuming I'll need to do the following:

- Build a service to append an element to the body
- That element should have a directive that will trigger... something or other?

But when I gave that a try, the directive didn't actually link up. For example:

```
angular.module("ui.sidePanel", [])
.service("$sidePanel", function($rootScope, $document){
  return{
    open: function(options){
        angular.element($document[0].body).append("<side-panel></side-panel>");
        console.log('Boop');
    }
  }
})
.directive("sidePanel", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log('Side Panel');
    }
  }
})
```

Would never log "Side Panel".

Comment: Couple of notes.  First, it's bad practice to name your own stuff with a $ prefix - that is reserved for angular core stuff.  Second, you most likely don't want to keep appending DOM nodes as you have it, intead write the DOM node controlled by a directive and ng-hide/ng-show based on state.  Lastly, in your example, nothing calls $sidePanel.open()

Comment: @MattPileggi I suppose your right, I was just trying to go by ui.bootstrap's example. you're entirely right that I won't want to keep appending DOM nodes, but I was hoping for something a little more elegant then a ng-show/ng-hide since I would like to reuse this multiple places. Perhaps writing up a directive is the best way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Just appending html is not sufficient for your purposed, you would also need to compile the html (with `$compile`) in order for it to run the directive.

That being said I would suggest an alternative approach where the service does not manipulate dom, since that is not a best practice.

Your service can just hold the state of the modal, which your directive can watch and choose which content to show. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H34PA/1/) you can play with.

The service just holds a value for the modal to look at

```
myApp.factory('service', function () {
    return {    
        value: {
            data: ''
        }
    };
});
```

The directive scopes that value, so it knows when to show

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $scope.value = service.value;
}
```

Now whenever you set the value of the service, the directive can adjust accordingly

EDIT: some ui.bootstrap code

They seem to be using a service to fetch template urls and that pass it as content to the directive.

```
// In the $modal service
      function getTemplatePromise(options) {
        return options.template ? $q.when(options.template) :
          $http.get(options.templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache}).then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
          });
      }
```

If you are looking to dive in more you can check out their [source](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I remember being a little disgusted at myself for attaching elements to the DOM through the `service`, but I wasn't sure how else to do it without sticking the `<side-panel>` tag in my template. I should probably just suck it up and do it how you described, but I'm still curious to know how ui.bootstrap does it.

Comment: I added a little tidbit in my answer about ui.bootstrap.