# How do I inject this directive into my AngularJs controller?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I want to use the code form [this Plunk](https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/).

It has a directive:

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
```

and a service

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
```

and the example injects into the controller thusly:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
```

I have this:

```
angular
    .module('Dashboard')
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);
```

and

```
function DashboardController($rootScope, $scope, $http, 
                             $interval, $state, $location)
{
```

But I can't figure out how to inject the file upload into my controller :-(

Comment: what is module name for `fileUpload` service?

Comment: Isn't it in the Plunkr? My module is called `UplaodStuff`

Comment: so try this `angular.module('Dashboard',['UplaodStuff ']) ...   and `function DashboardController($rootScope, $scope, $http, 
                             $interval, $state, $location,fileUpload)` and also inject `UplaodStuff` js file before `Dashboard` module js.
{

Comment: Sorry, I am a stupid n00b. Why am I injecting my own module name here?

Comment: because you define `fileUpload` service in separate module. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109291/how-do-i-write-a-custom-module-for-angularjs

Comment: Can I somehow just add the `fileUpload` service to my own module, to make things simpler? I am trying to make this as simple as possible, so that even I can understand it.

Comment: yes you can. change module name to own module name.

Comment: Can you please post a simple answer to show me how to code it.  It is clear that you know how, but I cannot quite follow you. Code would be clearer than text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. i think your problem is for module name.i define `fileUpload` service in same module for `DashboardController`

```
  var myApp = angular.module("yourAppName",[]);
  myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  ...

  myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
  ...

 myApp.controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);


function DashboardController($rootScope, $scope, $http, 
                         $interval, $state, $location,fileUpload)
   {
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I finally found a reasonably simple way to upload files to the server.

Comment: Glad to help you :)